# How to build a select query to specify the record which is already existed in other table

Tags: oracle11g

I want to specify that a phone number is already existed in other table or not. If it is existed then it must show me 'yes' otherwise show me 'no'. For exanple:
Select Name,  PHONE_NO, (Select 'yes' from cdr_personal_info c , tec_personal_info t where c.phone_no=t.phone_no) CDR_existence   from TEC_PERSONAL_INFO;
The above query display 'yes' with all columns of TEC_PERSONAL_INFO table it should only display 'yes' with one column which is existed in CDR_PERSONAL_INFO table.
Note: these two tables does not have any kinds of relationship with each other.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [an `exists` condition](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/EXISTS-Condition.html#GUID-20259A83-C42B-4E0D-8DF4-9A2A66ACA8E7) around your subquery - though you don't need to refer to the driving table again - within [a case expression](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/CASE-Expressions.html#GUID-CA29B333-572B-4E1D-BA64-851FABDBAE96):

```
select t.name,
  t.phone_no,
  case when exists (
      select null from cdr_personal_info c where c.phone_no=t.phone_no
    ) then 'yes' else 'no' end as cdr_existence
from tec_personal_info t
```

Or you could use an outer join, but you might have to deal with duplicates if the `cdrpersonal_info` table can have the same phone number more than once:

```
select t.name,
  t.phone_no,
  case when c.phone_no is null then 'no' else 'yes' end as cdr_existence
from tec_personal_info t
left join cdr_personal_info c on c.phone_no=t.phone_no
```

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e8238d63263f079ba3087b36be8690d6) with some made-up data.

Comment: Thank you sir your answer was very helpful for me.